# android facing problems to use fragments in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-2.2-froyo

I am starting my programming with fragments. i want to do it for android 2.2 first then for android 3.0/3.1/3.2.

I added Compatibility package , all things i did. 
What i want just give me some sample example for android 2.2 fragments for better understanding that how to use fragments in application.

Comment: :how did u solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

there are the [Api4+](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/index.html) and the [API 13+](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support13Demos/index.html) demos. You can download an install on your phone and try it and choose which one is the best for you. The source code is very helpful and commented.

Comment: i am using that source code using android 2.2 . But it showing some errors. Why?

Comment: In value-v11 folder there is styles.xml. There showing error,    no resource found for android:Theme.Holo

Comment: There some error in the examples, delete the holo theme an try it again.